# Licking fingers for Mayim Acharonim?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, water, maseches-machshirin

Since saliva is one of the seven "liquids" (a subcategory of water, cf. Machshirin 6:5), would licking or sucking on one's own fingers fulfill the obligation of Mayim Acharonim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Halachipedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Mayim_Achronim#Water_that_is_fit_for_Mayim_Achronim):

> Water that is fit for Mayim Achronim:
>
> 1. One shouldn’t use scalding hot water, rather lukewarm water is permitted and it preferable to use cold water. Hot water that cooled is also permitted.
> 2. Bitter, dirty, or smelly water not fit for animals to drink is permitted.
> 3. **Saliva is unfit; if nothing is available is better than nothing.** (Sources cited, there are: Peni Mabin O”C 38, Minchat Elazar 3:54, and Sherit Yehuda Blum 17 are stringent against the Torat Yekutiel Rosenberg O”C 6 who is lenient)
> 4. If there’s no water, one can use other liquids but not wine, yet if nothing else is available then one should wash with wine.